# Until a specific substring

Tags: variables, batch-file, substring

I need a batch command to return everything until after a certain substring.

What I mean, is when I have a string like this: `"Hi! How are you doing? I don't care!!!!!"` I can execute a command that gives me everything until after `"?"`.

I looked around the web and didn't find anything that I wanted. I found one method that took everything until after a substring and changed it:

```
set name=123456789
set blablabla=%name:*5=5%
```

This returns `"56789"` to the variable `blablabla`. The strings in my program are not going to be specific, so this won't work.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) and [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
$ string1='Hello my name is Foobar? What do I care!'
$ string2=$(echo $string1 | sed 's/^.*\? //')
$ echo $string2
What do I care!
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood your requirements fully. But I think PowerShell is a better option for this. However, you can use following script to get all characters upto given delimiter.

```
@echo off
set delim=%1
set input=%2
for /f "delims=%upto%" %%i in ("%input%") do (
echo %i
goto :eof
)
```

Sample run command:

```
stringupto.bat 5 123456789
```

Output:

```
1234
```